# How to display data in AbstractTableModel using java?

Tags: java, database, swing, jframe, abstracttablemodel

I have created a [JFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK4Ej.png) and I want to create an AbstractTableModel to display the data from database using dbquery in the grey box.

This is the first time I am doing this and I have been struggling for very long, really hope to receive some help! Thank you.

```
JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean conditionOK = false;

            if(chckbxr.isSelected()==false && chckbxr_1.isSelected()==false && chckbxr_2.isSelected()==false && chckbxr_3.isSelected()==false){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Please select client account");
            }
            else if(fromDate.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter starting date");
            }
            else if(toDate.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter end date");
            }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(fromDate.getText()) > Integer.parseInt(toDate.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "End date is earlier than starting date");
            }
            else
            conditionOK = true;

            if(conditionOK==true){

                int fromYear = Integer.parseInt(fromDate.getText().substring(0, 4));
                int fromMonth = Integer.parseInt(fromDate.getText().substring(4,6))-1;
                int fromDay = Integer.parseInt(fromDate.getText().substring(6,8));
                int toYear = Integer.parseInt(toDate.getText().substring(0, 4));
                int toMonth = Integer.parseInt(toDate.getText().substring(4,6))-1;
                int toDay = Integer.parseInt(toDate.getText().substring(6,8));

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
                DateFormat formatter;
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                Calendar convertedToDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                convertedToDate.set(toYear,toMonth,toDay);
                Calendar convertedFromDate =Calendar.getInstance();
                convertedFromDate.set(fromYear,fromMonth,fromDay);

                int MonthDifferenceCount = 1;
                //calculate months difference
                for ( MonthDifferenceCount=1; convertedFromDate.compareTo(convertedToDate) <0; MonthDifferenceCount++)
                {
                    convertedFromDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                    convertedFromDate.set(convertedFromDate.DAY_OF_MONTH,convertedFromDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                }

                convertedToDate.set(toYear,toMonth,toDay);
                convertedFromDate.set(fromYear,fromMonth,fromDay);


                //DateArray and PreDate Array are used to store date as date format. Shall be use for tradeDate and SetlDate
                Date preDateArray[] = new Date[MonthDifferenceCount];
                Date DateArray [] = new Date[MonthDifferenceCount];
                for (int i=0; i <MonthDifferenceCount; i++)
                {
                    convertedFromDate.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
                    convertedFromDate.set(convertedFromDate.DAY_OF_MONTH,convertedFromDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    preDateArray[i] = convertedFromDate.getTime();
                    try {
                        preDateArray[i] = (Date)formatter.parse(sdf.format(preDateArray[i]));
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }  

                    convertedFromDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                    convertedFromDate.set(convertedFromDate.DAY_OF_MONTH,convertedFromDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    DateArray[i] = convertedFromDate.getTime();
                    try {
                        DateArray[i] = (Date)formatter.parse(sdf.format(DateArray[i]));
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }  
                    convertedFromDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);   
                }

                summaryFromDate = sdf2.format(DateArray[0]);
                summaryToDate = sdf2.format(DateArray[DateArray.length-1]);

                String DateList[] = new String[MonthDifferenceCount];
                String PreDateList[] = new String[MonthDifferenceCount];
                for (int i=0; i<DateArray.length; i++)  
                {
                    DateList[i] = sdf1.format(DateArray[i]);
                    PreDateList[i] = sdf1.format(preDateArray[i]);
                }


                ArrayList<String> cltAccList = new ArrayList<String>();

                if(chckbxr.isSelected()==true){
                    cltAccList.add("10190R");
                }
                if(chckbxr_1.isSelected()==true){
                    cltAccList.add("10230R");
                }
                if(chckbxr_2.isSelected()==true){
                    cltAccList.add("10280R");
                }
                if(chckbxr_3.isSelected()==true){
                    cltAccList.add("10290R");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btnSubmit.setBounds(37, 643, 89, 23);
    add(btnSubmit);
```

After submitting the date the AbstractTableModel should actually display the data from the database.

**Table Model:**

```
public class MTableModel {

public static class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Object[]> data;
        private List<String> columnNames;

        public MyModel(List<String> columnNames, List<Object[]> data) {
            super();
            this.columnNames = columnNames;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames.get(column);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return data.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
        }
    }



    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(MTableModel.class.getSimpleName());
        List<String> columns = Arrays.asList("Name", "Gender");
        List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Object[] value = new Object[2];
            data.add(value);
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(new MyModel(columns, data));
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MTableModel().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: working code examples from Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables, or ResultSetTableModel, or TableFromDatabase, voting to close too

Comment: Why not post something you coded so far, some code would be appreciated to get some support

Comment: @kaya I have edited my post. Basically what I am trying to do is to display the data that happened in the period of time. I already have the sql query to generate the data. The problem I'm facing now is to create a table and display it in JFrame. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: so this is your actual code?
you did not start implementing a Tablemodel yet if i understand correctly?

Comment: @kaya hi, I just completed the TableModel, sorry for causing any inconvenience!

Comment: so now just set your table with the tablemodel(new MyModel..)

Answer (score 2):

Your `value` arrays are getting initialized to a pair of `null` entries by default.

```
Object[] value = new Object[2];
```

Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    Object[] value = new Object[]{"Name" + i, Math.random() < .5 ? "M" : "F"};
    data.add(value);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I attach you a FULL EXAMPLE of the situation:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * Example class to learn how to use AbstractTableModel
 * 
 * @author Moreno
 *
 */
public class Example extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // default serialVersionUID

    /**
     * Example class, is a JFrame
     * 
     */
    public Example() {
        super("Example");

        TableModelCustom myModel = new TableModelCustom();  //Create my table model
        JTable table = new JTable(myModel);                 //Create JTable
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(480, 70));   //Prefered size scroll

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);    //Create scroll with table

        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");           //Create JButton
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Click me2");         //Create JButton2
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     //Listener onClick...

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Change data
                Object[][] data = { { "Rick", "Mourt", "Main Street", 55, true} };

                //Send data to the model
                myModel.setData(data);
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {        //Listener onClick...

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Change data
                Object[][] data = { { "Thomas", "Mourt", "Main Street 50", 55, true },
                        { "Rich", "Fua", "Main Street 2", 25, false }, 
                        { "Alan", "Poe", "Main Street 3", 12, true } };

                //Send data to the model
                myModel.setData(data);
            }
        });

        //Add components to the window
        add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);        //Add first button
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);   //Add scroll pane
        add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);       //Add first button


        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * Model
     * 
     * @author Moreno
     *
     * @see AbstractTableModel
     */
    class TableModelCustom extends AbstractTableModel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // Columns
        private String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Surname", "Direction", "Age", "Sport" };
        // Data
        private Object[][] data = { { "Peter", "Serry", "Rue....", 5, false },
                { "Paul", "Hey", "XXX", 13, true },
                { "Patriks", "--", "XXX", 26, false },
                { "Alice", "Hall", "XXX", 24, true },
                { "Mary", "Houstong", "XXX", 12, false } };

        /**
         * This method receives the new data vector, and update the table
         * 
         * @param data
         *            with new values
         */
        public void setData(Object[][] data) {
            this.data = data;       //Save data..
            fireTableDataChanged(); //Update table
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();  //Create the window
    }
}
```

Please adapt it to your needs